# UIImage as CAShapeLayer contents

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

If I create a CAShapeLayer with just a background color it shows up, but if i set the content to an image, nothing shows.

```
CAShapeLayer* leftDot = [CAShapeLayer layer];
leftDot.opacity = 1.0;
leftDot.frame = CGRectMake(leftRef.CGPointValue.x, leftRef.CGPointValue.y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
leftDot.position = CGPointMake(leftRef.CGPointValue.x + 4, leftRef.CGPointValue.y + 4);
leftDot.cornerRadius = radius;
[leftDot setContents:[UIImage imageNamed: @"glow.png"]];

[self.layer addSublayer: leftDot];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CAShapeLayer doesn't work that way. You would create a normal CALayer with the image as its content and then use the shape layer as the mask of that layer to achieve the effect you are after.

Answer (score 13):

*[NOTE: updated to Swift 2.2 and Swift 3]*

#### Quick answer: use CALayer

As explained in [CAShapeLayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CAShapeLayer), a `CAShapeLayer` is used for drawing shapes using a custom path. Setting an image as its `contents` will simply be ignored.

If you just want to show an image in a layer (let's suppose your file is named `image.png`), you can use a `CALayer` and set its `contents` property so that it references the `CGImage` representation of your image:

*Swift 2.2:*

```
let layer = CALayer()
layer.contents = UIImage(named: "image")?.CGImage
```

*Swift 3:*

```
let layer = CALayer()
layer.contents = UIImage(named: "image")?.cgImage
```

---

#### Longer answer: keep using CAShapeLayer

Since the OP asked specifically about `CAShapeLayer`, the question may read like "How can I crop an image into a specific shape using `CAShapeLayer`?"

There are two solutions I'd suggest you try:

**1) Masking**

Create a normal `CALayer` and set the image as its `contents`. Then create a `CAShapeLayer` with the path you like and use it as the first layer's `mask`.

*Swift 2.2:*

```
let imageLayer = CALayer()
imageLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "image")?.CGImage // Assign your image
imageLayer.frame = ... // Define a frame

let maskPath = UIBezierPath(...) // Create your path
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath

imageLayer.mask = maskLayer // Set the mask
```

*Swift 3:*

```
let imageLayer = CALayer()
imageLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "image")?.cgImage // Assign your image
imageLayer.frame = ... // Define a frame

let maskPath = UIBezierPath(...) // Create your path
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath

imageLayer.mask = maskLayer // Set the mask
```

Don't forget to set the right frames and paths, and you should be able to achieve the effect you wanted.

**2) Fill color**

Create a `CAShapeLayer` with the path you like, then use your image as its `fillColor`.

*Swift 2.2:*

```
let path = UIBezierPath(...) // Create your path
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.path = path.CGPath

let image = UIImage(named: "image") // Assign your image
layer.fillColor = UIColor(patternImage: image!).CGColor
```

*Swift 3:*

```
let path = UIBezierPath(...) // Create your path
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.path = path.cgPath

let image = UIImage(named: "image") // Assign your image
layer.fillColor = UIColor(patternImage: image!).cgColor
```

You may find this approach easier at first, but controlling the way the image fills your shape is not trivial at all.

Comment: Thank you for adding the reason. I was trying to set the image as CAShapeLAyer's content. Now I realised, my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the image to appear by setting the `fillColor` rather than the `contents`:

```
layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]].CGColor;
```

Comment: Could you please further elaborate on how your answer solves the question?

Comment: you can solve the problem using the code above like this: <code>CAShapeLayer* leftDot = [CAShapeLayer layer];
leftDot.opacity = 1.0;
leftDot.frame = CGRectMake(leftRef.CGPointValue.x, leftRef.CGPointValue.y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
leftDot.position = CGPointMake(leftRef.CGPointValue.x + 4, leftRef.CGPointValue.y + 4);
leftDot.cornerRadius = radius;
leftDot.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]].CGColor;
[self.layer addSublayer: leftDot];<code>

Answer (score 2):

```
layerName.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.PNG"] CGImage];
```

Comment: What results are you getting when doing this? It has never worked for me with CAShapeLayers. Instead shape layers stroke and fill their path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the CGImage for the layer

```
leftDot.fillColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor ;
[leftDot setContents:(__bridge id)[UIImage imageNamed: @"glow.png"].CGImage];
```