# How to get CAShapeLayer's frame confront to its superview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

Can anybody help me to get frame of CAShapeLayer which is been added in UIImageView as a SubLayer?

Following is my code for the same:

```
CAShapeLayer  *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.15].CGColor;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
shapeLayer.zPosition = 1;
[_imgBackground.layer insertSublayer:shapeLayer atIndex:1];

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(50, 50)]; // left top point of rack
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 50)]; // right top point of rack
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)]; // right bottom point of rack
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(50, 100)]; // left bottom point of rack
[path closePath]; // closing rectangle/path

shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
```

As I know we can get frame from the following line:

```
CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(shapeLayer.path);
```

But it only returns frame according to `self.view`

I want its frame according to UIImageView.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632200/uiimage-as-cashapelayer-contents) your case?

Comment: check my ans and let me know ..

Comment: Try with CALayer.

Comment: You can use [convertRect](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622504-convertrect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I got the answer from James's comment. Following line saved my day:

```
CGRect bounds = [self.view convertRect:CGPathGetBoundingBox(shapeLayer.path) toView:_imgBackground];
```

from [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622504-convertrect) reference.