# Unable to set image for cashape layer

Tags: ios, xcode

1.i have created CAshapelayer and also  inserted one lable sucessfully in CAshapelayer,but now i'm trying to set image in layer but it was not working.

2. help me to make Zoom in animation  for this layer.

   ```
        CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(50, 250, 100, 100)] CGPath]];
   circleLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"001-forward.png"] CGImage];
   circleLayer.contentsGravity=kCAGravityResize;
     //  circleLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
   [circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor brownColor] CGColor]];
   [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];

    [[self.view layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];
   CATextLayer *label = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
   [label setFont:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
   [label setFontSize:15];
   [label setFrame:CGRectMake(50,300, 100, 50)];
   [label setString:@"GM"];
   [label setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
   [label setForegroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];

   [circleLayer addSublayer:label];
   ```

Comment: Remove .png from image name and then try the code, see if it sets the image?

Comment: what you mean with zoom in animation, can you post a gif or something we can see?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 nothing change

Comment: @ReinierMelian make present as zoom in the layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that you can´t add an `UIImage` as content for `CAShape Layer`,as you can see here [UIImage as CAShapeLayer contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632200/uiimage-as-cashapelayer-contents) so I had modified your code adding the Image into `CALayer` and adding that layer to your circleLayer

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(50, 250, 100, 100);
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:frame] CGPath]];
circleLayer.contentsGravity=kCAGravityResize;
//  circleLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
[circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor brownColor] CGColor]];
//[circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];

[[self.view layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];
CATextLayer *label = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
[label setFont:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
[label setFontSize:15];
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(50,300, 100, 50)];
[label setString:@"GM"];
[label setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
[label setForegroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];

CALayer * imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
[imageLayer setContents: (__bridge id _Nullable)([[UIImage imageNamed:@"test"] CGImage])];
imageLayer.frame = frame; // Define a frame
imageLayer.contentsGravity=kCAGravityResize;

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[maskLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)] CGPath]];
imageLayer.mask = maskLayer;

[circleLayer addSublayer:imageLayer];
[circleLayer addSublayer:label];
```

[image]

Comment: thank you its working fine i need to make this circlelayer  to zoom in animation

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(50, 250, 100, 100)] CGPath]];
circleLayer.bounds = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(50, 250, 100, 100)] bounds];
circleLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
[circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor brownColor] CGColor]];
//Use .png if you store your image outside of .xcassets
circleLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"001-forward.png"]].CGColor;

[[self.view layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];
```